# Пишем ли мы названия музгрупп в кавычках?

Tags: кавычки

Пишем ли мы названия музгрупп в кавычках?

> И зачем с тобою было нам знакомиться? («Голубые гитары», «Ветер северный»).

> И зачем с тобою было нам знакомиться? (Голубые гитары, «Ветер северный»).

Comment: Кавыччки нужны.